# Retrieving the tags for a post from a Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I'm new to Wordpress plugins, and editing someone else's to add functionality. I need to retrieve the tags for a particular post.

The [get post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) function is already in use inside the plugin and returns category information. Unfortunately nothing is returned for tags.

The [get the tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) function appears to be most appropriate but it only runs inside the Wordpress loop. My understanding is that plugins run outside the loop.

I haven't found anything else in the API reference.

**How is it possible to retrieve the tags for a post?**

Comment: Plugins don't necessarily run outside the loop. It depends on which hook you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
get_the_tags($post->ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/191245

A couple of solutions behind that link.